# vbscript sms query by query id

Tags: sql, vbscript, sms, configurationmanager, sccm

I have this code and it doesn't work, gives me an error "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub" on the line where I run RunQuery (SCCMConnectionString, queryId)

```
Sub RunQuery(connection, queryId)
    Dim query
    Dim queryResults
    Dim queryResult 


    ' Get query.
    Set query=connection.Get("SMS_Query.QueryID='" & queryId  & "'" )

    If err.number<>0 Then
        WScript.echo "Couldn't get Queries"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Run query.
    WScript.echo query.Name
    WScript.echo "----------------------------------"

    Set queryResults=connection.ExecQuery(query.Expression)
    For Each queryResult In queryResults
        wscript.echo "     " & queryResult.Name
    Next
    If queryResults.Count=0 Then
        WScript.echo "      no query results"
    End If
End Sub

SCCMConnectionString = chr(34) & "Server=OAK-PRD-SCC01;Database=CM_TIM;trusted_connection=True" & chr(34)
queryID = "SMS024"
RunQuery (SCCMConnectionString, queryId)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you can not use parantheses when you call a **sub** in VBScript.

Try this. It should work.

```
 RunQuery SCCMConnectionString, queryId
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference between a `Sub` and a `Function` in VBScript is that a function returns a value and a sub does not. Parentheses are allowed/required when invoking a function and using its return value. They are not allowed at all when invoking a sub in the normal way.

Here's the corrected line (#30):

```
RunQuery SCCMConnectionString, queryId
```

Here's an MS doc that goes into more detail: [VBScript Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx9ceb2w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Curiously, you are allowed to use parentheses if you invoke the sub using the `Call` command.

```
Call RunQuery(SCCMConnectionString, queryId)
```

Comment: Personally, I find this to be one (of numerous) irritating VBScript features that rub my programmer fur the wrong way. I can't think of a good reason why MS implemented it this way.